# FilteredPages in tablesorter with server-side filtering

Tags: ajax, filtering, server-side, tablesorter

I'm not sure how to update the `filteredPages` value in tablesorter when using server-side filtering.

I am using version 2.13.2 and am able to create custom `output` which is then accessible in `p.ajaxData` so that the pager displays the correct number of items shown, etc (eg, "1 to 10 of 30 (40 total)". But I don't see how to change the page dropdown at `select.gotoPage` to reflect the reduced number of filtered pages. I've tried both the pager widget as well `tablesorterPager`.

For example, let's say the dropdown normally allows you to choose pages 1 through 4. Now you filter and the filtered items fit on 3 pages - how is the dropdown reduced to showing only 3 pages as options?

Answer (score 0):

The pager select dropdown recalculates how many pages exist (when rows are filters) each time the page is changed or the table content is filtered.

In this case, the `filteredPages` should be information that your server provides to the plugin because when using ajax, the pager automatically defaults to server side sorting and filtering. Make sure to update the pager's [`ajaxUrl` option](http://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/#pager-ajaxurl) to include the filter and sort parameters. For example:

```
$(function(){
  $("table")
    .tablesorter()
    .tablesorterPager({
      ajaxUrl: "http://mydatabase.com?page={page}&size={size}&{sortList:col}&{filterList:fcol}",
      ajaxProcessing: function(ajax){
        // do something with the ajax
        return [ formatted_data, total_rows ];
      }
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: The server is returning the `filteredPages` (actually, it's returning the information needed to calculate `filteredPages`), but I'm not sure what to do with it within ajaxProcessing to get the dropdown to change automatically. Currently I'm putting the info in `table.config.pager.ajaxData`, then using `.bind` upon `pagerComplete` and simply rebuilding the drop down. This works but thought I was probably overcomplicating things.

Comment: It would help if you could share a demo or the code you are using to update the table. You shouldn't need to rebuild the dropdown.

Comment: The table requires admin access so I've set up a test demo and have sent you an email to your gmail address (from my address in my stackoverflow profile) with the information to access it. Thanks for taking a look!