# Tablesorter flashing duplicate rows while sorting with ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, sorting, server-side, tablesorter

When using server-side sorting in tablesorter 2.13.2 together with the pager, double the number of rows will show while the sort is processing. For example, if 5 rows show per page, when a header is clicked to sort, 10 rows will show while the sort is processing, and then the correct 5 rows are shown when the sort process has ended. It happens whether the beta pager widget is used or the old pager. It doesn't seem to happen the first time a sort is triggered, but happens on subsequent sorts.

The code that adds the additional rows starts on line 326 of `jquery.tablesorter.js`:

```
if (!c.appender || !c.removeRows) {
    l = r[pos].length;
    for (j = 0; j < l; j++) {
        $tb.append(r[pos][j]);
    }
}
```

I am not using any features for appending or removing rows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was just resolved in the latest update of tablesorter - [reported here](https://github.com/Mottie/tablesorter/issues/411).

All you need to do is [download the latest version](http://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/index.html).

Comment: This worked. But I now have a `.trigger('search', false)` that I was using for an external filter that no longer works. Will post a demo separately.

Comment: Sent you a separate mail regarding a demo of this issue plus the one discussed [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19760156/filteredpages-in-tablesorter-with-server-side-filtering)

Comment: Found the solution to the `.trigger('search', false)` issue mentioned above. Using version 2.13.3 replaced this with the method shown [here](http://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/example-widget-filter-any-match.html). In particular, used this code: `$(".search").bind('search keyup', function (e) { $('table').trigger('search', [ [this.value] ]);});`